# I am Unable to access to root user in oracle linux server

Tags: linux, users, login, root, cloud

I was configuring Ansible on my server where I created an Ansible user on all servers and gave them sudo access so whenever I ssh to another server using an Ansible user it should not ask me for a password. I successfully configured it on two servers but when I was doing it on another server by making changes in `/etc/sudoers/` file the system became unresponsive and then I restarted my terminal and now when I am trying to login server to the root user it is throwing an error

```
$ sudo su

/etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 121 <<< sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 121 sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

Comment: Is there any question? You describe an effect, the reason is obvious. What has to be done is obvious.

Answer (score 2):

You've broken the `sudoers` file, and so `sudo` will refuse to allow any access. If you have the root password then you can use it to fix the problem:

```
su -
visudo
```

If you haven't, then you're going to need to start the system with a rescue disk and reset the `sudoers` file that way. Far far more complicated.

Don't edit the `/etc/sudoers` file manually without using `visudo` as it performs syntax checks to prevent exactly this kind of situation.

Incidentally, there's no need to use `sudo su` (it uses `sudo` to get root privileges, and then you ask `su`, already as root, to give you them again). `sudo -s` or maybe `sudo -i` is completely sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have the root password, but your user account is in the `wheel` group (or `sudo` group for Debian/Ubuntu), there is one more thing to try:

```
pkexec visudo
```

It should prompt for your password (more verbosely than `sudo`) and then allow you to edit the `/etc/sudoers` file.

If you don't have any active root sessions remaining and cannot get them (neither with `sudo` nor `pkexec`), then I'm afraid there is no way to fix this without some downtime.

I am not familiar with Oracle Cloud OPC. But since you apparently are on a cloud server and have several such servers, the last way to fix it would be to forcibly shut the server down using the cloud management interface, then temporarily disconnect the virtual system disk from the problematic cloud server and present that virtual disk to a second cloud server as an extra disk. Then you could mount the root filesystem of the problem server to e.g. `/mnt` in the second server ("repair server"), and run `visudo -f /mnt/etc/sudoers` to fix the syntax error. After doing this, you would unmount and disconnect the disk from the repair server, and present it back to the problem server.

If the cloud management interface does not have the necessary features to allow you do this to your VMs, then you will have to contact your cloud operator (i.e. Oracle?) for support. They should be quite familiar with problems of this type: you are definitely not the first one to have lost root access to your cloud server because of a typo.

Comment: Yes you are right when I run the command pkexec visudo it prompts for the password of the current user as we have our infrastructure on Oracle Cloud OPC user doesn't require any password for login so we are unable to proceed further. Nor do we have any password required for root users. Is there anything else we can do to resolve this issue.